# Proving periodicity of sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-series

If we *define* the sine and cosine functions by their Maclaurin expansions, how do we prove they are periodic with period $2\pi$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/how-to-prove-periodicity-of-sinx-or-cosx-starting-from-the-taylor-seri  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610217/parity-through-series-expansion

Comment: Why the negative vote?